# Inverse operation to padding in Jax

Tags: pytorch, padding, jax

I'm trying to learn how to use **Jax** and I stumbled upon the problem of converting the `torch.nn.functionnal.pad` function into **Jax**. There is a function to perform padding but I would like in the same way as in **PyTorch** use negative numbers in the padding (e.g `F.pad(array, [-1,-1])`).

Does anyone have an idea or had the same problem ?

Answer (score 2):

The [`jax.lax.pad`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.pad.html) function accepts negative padding indices, although the API is a bit different than that of `torch.nn.functional.pad`. For example:

```python
from jax import lax
import jax.numpy as jnp

x = jnp.ones((2, 3))
y = lax.pad(x, padding_config=[(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0)], padding_value=0.0)
print(y)
# [[0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]]

x = lax.pad(y, padding_config=[(0, 0, 0), (-1, -1, 0)], padding_value=0.0)
print(x)
# [[1. 1. 1.]
#  [1. 1. 1.]]
```

If you wish, you could wrap this with a function that has similar semantics to the torch version. Here's a quick attempt:

```python
def jax_pad(input, pad, mode='constant', value=0):
  """JAX implementation of torch.nn.functional.pad

  Warning: this has not been thoroughly tested!
  """
  if mode != 'constant':
    raise NotImplementedError("Only mode='constant' is implemented")
  assert len(pad) % 2 == 0
  assert len(pad) // 2 <= input.ndim
  pad = list(zip(*[iter(pad)]*2))
  pad += [(0, 0)] * (input.ndim - len(pad))
  return lax.pad(
      input,
      padding_config=[(i, j, 0) for i, j in pad[::-1]],
      padding_value=jnp.array(value, input.dtype))

x = jnp.ones((2, 3))
y = jax_pad(x, (1, 1))
print(y)
# [[0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]]

x = jax_pad(y, (-1, -1))
print(x)
# [[1. 1. 1.]
#  [1. 1. 1.]]
```